# Why can't I change text color but I can still change the color of font awesome icons?

Tags: color, links, fontawesome

I have what it seems a very simple question, but I still cannot solve it, and I haven't been able to reproduce the problem outside Friggeri's CV template (sorry for that).

The whole thing is trying to have a default text color that still allows me to change the color of specific words/phrases.

I am using [Friggeri's CV template](https://github.com/afriggeri/cv) with the same friggeri-cv.cls (I have only changed all the Helvetica fonts to Arial and added backend=biber to the \RequirePackage{biblatex} line).

This is a MWE, where you can see text doesn't change color, but the flag does. Isn't font awesome considered text?

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
\listfiles
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}

\begin{document}
\header{name}{surname}
       {occupation}

% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
  \section{sec}
    aaa
    bbb
\end{aside}


\section{sec}
\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {2014}
    {some text here}
    {more here}
    {and more text

    and \textcolor{red}{text in color}

    and an icon \textcolor{red}{\faFlag}

    and even a \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{link}
    }
\end{entrylist}


\end{document}
```

Now, I know there is this line in the .cls file

```
 \colorlet{textcolor}{gray}
```

that controls default text color, but I still want the default text color to be like that, why doesn't \textcolor{red} override it?

I only get colored text when I comment that line...

This brings me to the problem of customizing links... I use the following line in the .cls file (but it doesn't work if I use it in the .tex file) to remove the box around links:

```
 \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

But can I make all links be blue and underlined, for example? The option urlcolor=blue in the above command doesn't seem to do anything...

EDIT:

I get the following with the MWE above:

[image: this]

A big big plus would be to get rid of the underfull hbox warning too, if possible!

Many thanks

EDIT 2:

At the end of the log file, \listfiles lists the following:

```
 *File List*
friggeri-cv.cls    2012/04/30 CV class
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
luatex-loader.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)
fontspec.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2014/01/07 v4646 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2014/01/04 v4640 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2014/01/04 v4640 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
  luatex.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 LuaTeX basic definition package (HO)
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3basics.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2013/12/27 v4625 L3 Token lists
   l3seq.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2013/08/02 v4583 L3 Integers
 l3quark.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Quarks
   l3prg.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Control structures
 l3clist.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2013/08/25 v4587 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Property lists
   l3msg.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Messages
  l3file.sty    2013/10/13 v4596 L3 File and I/O operations
  l3skip.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2013/12/08 v4614 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Floating points
   l3box.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2013/12/14 v4624 L3 Coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2014/01/06 v4643 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
  xparse.sty    2013/12/31 v4634 L3 Experimental document command parser
luaotfload.sty    2014/02/05 v2.4-3 OpenType layout system
luatexbase.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Resource management for the LuaTeX macro progr
ammer
luatexbase-compat.sty    2011/05/24 v0.4 Compatibility tools for LuaTeX
luatexbase-modutils.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Module utilities for LuaTeX
luatexbase-loader.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Lua module loader for LuaTeX
luatexbase-regs.sty    2011/05/24 v0.4 Registers allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-attr.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Attributes allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-cctb.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Catcodetable allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-mcb.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Callback management for LuaTeX
fontspec-patches.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
fontspec-luatex.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu2enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu2lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many othe
r characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu2lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
fontspec.cfg
unicode-math.sty    2013/05/04 v0.7e Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
l3keys2e.sty    2013/12/31 v4634 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
  fix-cm.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
unicode-math-luatex.sty    
lualatex-math.sty    2013/08/03 v1.3 Patches for mathematics typesetting with Lu
aLaTeX
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
unicode-math-table.tex
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
 parskip.sty    2001/04/09 non-zero parskip adjustments
 textpos.sty    2014/01/03 v1.7j
biblatex.sty    2013/11/25 v2.8a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2013/11/25 v2.8a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)

kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
 verbose.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
authortitle.bbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 verbose.bbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 verbose.cbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
fontawesome.sty    2013/05/10 v3.1.1 font awesome icons
 english.lbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
      cv.bbl
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
      cv.out
      cv.out
 ***********
```

NEW EDIT:

I have tried to reproduce the error without using Friggeri's template, but with no success, the following line does not have the desired effect:
     \colorlet{textcolor}{blue}
But it has to be done that way, cause I don't want to touch Friggeri's template much... anybody has any idea?

This is the MWE

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\listfiles
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}

\colorlet{textcolor}{blue}

\begin{document}
and more text

and \textcolor{red}{text in color}

and an icon \textcolor{red}{\faFlag}

and even a \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{link}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I obtain [red coloured text](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IUOZ8.png)...

Comment: really? in my case only the flag is red... what can be the problem?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 14.04, using texlive 2013 and texmaker 4.1-1... any package or anything that I should check?

Comment: I compile it with LuaLaTeX and biber, in case it is relevant... does anybody have a clue? Thanks

Comment: Does anybody know why this happens and how to solve it? I'm really lost with this...

Comment: I have tried to compile Friggeri's CV with https://www.sharelatex.com/ (they have it with the name Fancy CV), just replacing "social networks" with "\textcolor{red}{social networks}" at the beginning, and it doesn't change the text colors either

Comment: `\ifdefined\@cv@print
  ...
  \colorlet{red}{gray}` is in the template. You need to tell it you are using it for screen.

Comment: yeah @YiannisLazarides, the relevant line is \colorlet{textcolor}{gray} if I comment it, I get the red colors, but I still want the default text color to be gray... and Werner said the unchanged .cls file worked for him...

Comment: Could you explain that last part please? How do I tell it I am using it for screen? Many thanks!

Comment: ah but that is for the print version, I am not using the print version

Comment: and I still get the color for the font awesome flag...

Comment: @Werner, what did you do, or what did you use to obtain red colored text?

Comment: @DaniCee: Since I didn't have the appropriate font, I assume the font features set by the class wasn't used, giving the desired output (just in a different font).

Comment: https://github.com/afriggeri/cv page does not seem to exist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Font coloring

The class `friggery-cv.cls` sets the `Color` attribute to the font:

```
\colorlet{textcolor}{gray}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Helvetica Neue Light}
```

Then the color is part of the font and cannot be changed from the outside. This is shown by the following example. `\textcolor{red}` is working as the red `\fbox` shows, but the font remains blue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Color=blue]{FreeSans}

\begin{document}
  Hello \textcolor{red}{\fbox{World}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Workarounds

- A new font *without* the feature `Color` can be defined. Then `\textcolor` applies to the colorless font.
- The following example changes the `Color` attribute of the current font:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont[Color=blue]{FreeSans}

  \begin{document}
    Hello {\addfontfeature{Color=red}World}
  \end{document}
  ```

  > [image: Result]

## Link customization

Blue underlined links, see `hyperref`'s [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf), section "Link border style".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  allbordercolors=blue,
  pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1},
}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{Test section}
  \label{sec:test}
  A reference to \hyperref[sec:test]{this section}.

  This example can be found in
  \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183340/16967}{this answer}.

  URL of the question:
  \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183170/16967}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: aaaaah ok, now I got it! I wasn't focusing on the relevant line of code... and that is why it doesn't affect font awesome!!

would it be possible to leave that line as is and then write another line like

\setchangesfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=red]{Helvetica Neue Light}

setchangesfont as opposed to setmainfont, and then call it somehow in the text to have all text changes in red?

Comment: @DaniCee: I have added an example, that locally changes the font attribute `Color` to red.